# How to always get the English version from docs.microsoft.com?

Tags: microsoft-documentation

When you visit https://learn.microsoft.com, it shows pages in my proper language.

Sometimes the pages are properly translated by humans, sometimes it is IA badly translated.

How to always get the English version from learn.microsoft.com?

Answer (score 0):

Info from related issue on github [MicrosoftDocs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/462)

A workaround is to set your google search parameters in 'english' and your native language in second choise.

Let me now if you got a better option.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There is no permanent out of the box solution. Use a addon like FFS MSDN in English ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ffs-msdn-in-english/ddaknggefjjgpnlhiejepbiplceedmfl/related), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/ffs-msdn-in-english/)). Or Redirector and add your own redirect rules.